# ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized; but the page loads just fine?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sqlcommand

I have an MVC setup, the Controller's `Index()` method launches a query against a database which then gets serialized to JSON and returned to the View. Almost each Controller is used only to display data so there are multiple such methods. As an example:

```
public string getSalesReport()
{
    return queryForJsonResult(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RetrieveSalesReport"]);
}
```

Is the method run. The `appSetting` I pass to it is the query (which is definitely correct). This method then does the following:

```
private string queryForJsonResult(string query)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    SqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();

    string jsonResult = bufferedResultBuilder(result);

    connection.Close();

    return jsonResult;
}

private string bufferedResultBuilder(SqlDataReader result)
{
    // Takes a result set and uses a buffer to build a JSON string.
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
    JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);
    jsonTextWriter.WriteStartArray();

    while (result.Read())
    {
        jsonTextWriter.WriteStartObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            jsonTextWriter.WritePropertyName(result.GetName(i));
            jsonTextWriter.WriteValue(result[i]);
        }

        jsonTextWriter.WriteEndObject();
    }

    jsonTextWriter.WriteEndArray();

    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

So it takes the result set and builds a JSON string out of it, one entry at a time. When I run the project, all of this seems to work just fine, the data is loaded properly. I also have unit tests which utilize `Stopwatch` to test how long these Controller methods take to run. When I run the unit test, however, this one particular entry catches an error:

> Result Message:    Test method
>   Dashboard.Tests.BenchmarkTests.salesOverviewLoadTime threw exception: 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader: CommandText property
>   has not been initialized

The query is definitely correct, and there are several other very similar examples which differ only in the initial query that is input. All of those methods work just fine. The stack trace for this error traces it back to `queryForJsonResult()`, `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`, but like I said it only does this for one of the many very similar methods used to display views.

Why is it that one query, which actually loads the data correctly, catches an error when I unit test? The unit tests are set up almost identically except for the Controller that is loaded and all of the other ones work just fine.

Comment: could this line be causing you the error `connection.Close();`

Comment: Hmm nope, still catches the error. The most baffling thing is the fact that the stack trace doesn't trace it to a part of the code that is distinct, but to a part of the code that is used MANY times, and in all the other cases it seems to work fine

Comment: can you put a break point after this `SqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();` and inspect result to see if there is infact anydata.. also what does this look like in your .config file `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RetrieveSalesReport"]`

Comment: Maybe your unit test runner isn't loading your config file.

Comment: in `queryForJsonResult`you should throw something if query is null or empty.

Comment: Stepping through it the `result` is what is expected and stepping through some JSON building seems to be fine as well (the first few entries were what was expected). `<add key="RetrieveSalesReport" value="SELECT DateRegistered, SalesPerson, TotalMargin, TotalVolume FROM dbo.SalesReport"/>`

Comment: @MichaelLiu was correct. I copied over the app settings from the main project to the tests project and now it all works fine. What is strange though is that there is no apparent reason all the other tests passed and only the one failed. I am staring hard at the tests now and it continues to baffle me...

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that is still strange to me. As @MichaelLiu pointed out, my `.config` files did not have the same `appSettings`. I copied over all of the `appSettings` that contained my queries and this resolved the issue. This does not necessarily explain, however, why all the other queries worked fine. I think I may have had one line of difference in the way the code exception handled e.g.

```
try {} catch {return;}
return;
```

as opposed to

```
try {
    return;
} catch {
    return;
}
```

Though there shouldn't be anything going wrong with `return`.

In any case, the solution is to make sure that both your project and it's unit test counterparts have same `.config` specifications, as needed.